# Wrong fs type for vboxsf after installing Guest Additions in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 in Virtualbox 4.3.12, and the command `sudo mount -t vboxsf mainshare /mnt/host` gives this error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on mainshare,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
(for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail  or so
```

I've installed Guest Additions like so: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`

Iso now located at: `/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`

I then mounted that ISO, and run sudo `sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`.  The installation seemed to go without errors, and I rebooted.

Any ideas?

edit: after 3 hours of Googling, I made this post.  2 minutes later, I find this one:https://askubuntu.com/questions/458286/getting-an-error-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-on-ubuntushared

Fixed.

Comment: This should be in SuperUser.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the guest OS you need to add the user to the vboxsf group.

sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf YourUserName